# root database location

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I don't know where to place the db so that when i will have my final app .exe, in it's folder i would have another data folder and in that folder the db.mdf. Here is my connection String :

`con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\alex\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Network_Remote_Monitoring\\Network_Remote_Monitoring\\data\\bd.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";`

(i.e. i would like a relative refference to the db, something like AttachDbFilename=".\data\bd.mdf" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does the relative path `data\\bd.mdf` not work in connection stings? e.g.,

```
con.ConnectionString = "DataSource=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='data\\bd.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

Otherwise you could use the current directory shortcut e.g., something like

```
string dbdirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\data\\bd.mdf"
con.ConnectionString = "DataSource=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='" 
+ dbdirectory + "';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

Or you could even open a file dialog and ask the user where they want to store the program data, and grab the full path from there.

EDIT: This is how you would achieve what you want, I would however suggest storing the db somewhere else like @TomTom suggested

Answer (score 2):

> that when i will have my final app
>   .exe, in it's folder i would have
>   another data folder and in that folder
>   the db.mdf

DO NOT DO THAT. Databases should never live:

- In the programs folder
- On a network drive (starting with \).

Why attach it like that anyway? In most cases (all I ever worked on) databases are explicitly crated on a server. Local databases should live either in the users program data (NOT DOCUMENTS!) folder or the shared one.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx for a list of special folders.

You want either ApplicationDataa, LocalApplicationData (not replicated) or CommonApplicationData, if you really have to keep the database local.

Comment: "...if you really have to keep the database local" (taking this as general advice) or, if you really want to, for example if you're using an in-process database solution, like SQLite.  I know the question wasn't on this, but there may be reasons to do this, in slightly different DB scenarios

Comment: But then, you know, this is not about in process databases to start with.